# WebView doesn't display anything

Tags: android, android-webview

This simple `WebView` doesn't work no matter what I did. In below code I also added my if condition if it matters.

```
String URL = "www.google.com.tr";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Welcome",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
    else    //Not connected
    {
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Internet disconnected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/myWebView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This `WebView` shows text "Welcome" so I think program should show websites without any issue. I am at my wit's end. I even tried changing Layout type, adding `ChromeView` instead normal web view. And tried to change content view from match_parent to wrap_content. But no luck by doing this.

I have internet permission in my Manifest

Comment: unsure about this, but maybe the protocol is required, so enter https://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the protocol information in your URL.

**Instead of:**

`String URL = "www.google.com.tr";`

**Use:**

`String URL = "https://www.google.com.tr";`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set

```
 webSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
```